# How add column of radio buttons or choose list to Data Grid in LightSwitch without adding column to table?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have table Licences(ID, NameOfOwner, Credits). It easy show it in DataGrid (for example in Editable DataGrid).

I want add one column to datagrid with few RadioButtons (Add 0 Credits, Add 50 Credits, Add 100 Credits, ...).

My first (working) solution was:
I start with add column to table (this is reason why I do not like this solution) and made him choise list.

How do it without adding column to table?

If it is impossible or very difficult what is solution second part of my question:
Also I want use RadioButtons because it will save one click per row (no click to expand choice list).

I tryed add Custom control, but it did not work. In new colmn are radiobuttons (or buttons, or checkbuttons) but they are not working.

Thanks,
I believe you will uderstand my English -)

My last workinkg soluttion is add buttons in grid row. Radio buttons would be better/nicer but in this solution I no need use custom control nor add column to table and it used only one click. (I have not problem using custom controls in single, only in datagrid).[image: my solution]

There is posibbility drag and drop buttons to a field. Till now I am happy with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

ockin:

you should [bind custom control value with column field value in some way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406736.aspx) in order to update the table.

If you don't chose custom control solution, then you can work with [list of choices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff852048.aspx).

Sorry about long time to reply, I supose you have achive it at this time.

Thanks, I believe you will uderstand my English too.